# jQuery append razor mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am creating dynamic tables with bootstrap.
I am getting data by ajax request and after I am making X bootstrap tables.
It works as below

```
success: function (succ) {
    $("#showMonth").text(monthArray[currentVisibleMonth - 1] + " " + currentVisibleYear);
    $("#tables").empty();
    var efficiencyDurations = succ.efficiencyDuration;
    var reportTables = succ.reportArray;
    var reportDurations = succ.totalDurations;
    $(succ.reportArray).each(function (i) {
        $(reportTables[i].data).each(function (datearray) {
            var date = new Date(parseInt(reportTables[i].data[datearray].Date.substr(6)));
            var formattedDate = $.format.date(date, "dd-MM-yyyy");
            reportTables[i].data[datearray].Date = formattedDate;
        });

        var duration = efficiencyDurations[i];
        $("#tables").append('<span class="text-primary"><b>' + reportTables[i].data[0].ClientName + " / " + reportTables[i].data[0].ProjectName + " / " + reportTables[i].data[0].TaskName + '</b></span> <span class="text-danger"><b>(' + duration + ")</b></span>");
        $("#tables").append("<table id=table" + i + '><thead><tr class="clickable-row"> <th data-field="Date" class="col-md-1"> Date </th><th data-field="Description" class="col-md-8"> Description</th> <th data-field="Duration" class="col-md-1">Real Duration</th> <th class="col-md-1" data-field="EfficiencyDuration">Duration</th> </tr></thead></table>');

        $("#table" + i).bootstrapTable({
            data: reportTables[i].data,
            striped: true
        });
    });
```

Now the point is that I want to make one column visible just for administrator.
But as I noticed I cannot append razorhtml with jQuery.append().

Does anyone have idea how to hide/show column depend of

> UserInRole("")?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying it this way.  Instead of trying to generate the logic of "UserInRole("")" in the HTML/razor side, just do it in Jquery.  Perform an Ajax call to the server to check if the user is an Admin.  If so, append the column.